# Google Analytics Crash and Exception report

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I wrote below code for Google analytics crash report.

```
GAI.sharedInstance().trackUncaughtExceptions = true
```

I am trying to generate crash report. I kept some code which is causing App crash but i can't see any report in behavior -> crash and exception.
Could you please suggest?

Comment: I am using simulator, it works ?

Comment: same here... no crashes report generated